# Opensea events api: Empty asset_events for some specific assets

Tags: polygon, opensea

When trying to get historical events for some assets on Opensea, I noticed some asset can return events correctly. But some return empty array.

This is an example that worked:

```
curl --request GET \
 --url 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/events?asset_contract_address=0xdcc2a6f7cf14b5d2fc0f2731faf0a37b914a0c82&token_id=2772&event_type=successful&only_opensea=false&offset=0&limit=20' \
 --header 'Accept: application/json' \
 --header 'X-API-KEY: XXXX'
```

However this does not work:

```
curl --request GET \
     --url 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/events?asset_contract_address=0xa5f1ea7df861952863df2e8d1312f7305dabf215&token_id=150238&event_type=successful&only_opensea=false&offset=0&limit=20' \
     --header 'Accept: application/json' \
     --header 'X-API-KEY: XXXX'
```

The second attempt returns an empty events array:

```
{"asset_events":[]}
```

This is the path to that specific asset, you can see that there are actually some events on the item page:
https://opensea.io/assets/matic/0xa5f1ea7df861952863df2e8d1312f7305dabf215/150238

Any clue what is going on? Is this a bug on Polygon asset?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Im running into the same issue on eth assets. cryptopunks even.

Answer (score 0):

Opensea API does not support Polygon (yet).